# Python subprocess called from Matlab fails

Tags: python, matlab, ubuntu, subprocess

I've hit a problem in trying to join some code from different sources in Matlab and I don't really know how to approach it. Essentially, I have some Python code for a compression algorithm called from the command line, which itself uses subprocess to run and communicate with C++ code compiled to a binary.

The function in Python (which is part of a larger object) looks like this:

```
def __extractRepeats(self, repeatClass):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["./repeats1/repeats11", "-i", "-r"+repeatClass, "-n2", "-psol"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process.stdin.write(' '.join(map(str,self.__concatenatedDAG)))
    text_file = ''
    while process.poll() is None:
        output = process.communicate()[0].rstrip()
        text_file += output
    process.wait()
    repeats=[]
    firstLine = False
    for line in text_file.splitlines():
        if firstLine == False:
            firstLine = True
            continue
        repeats.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
    return repeats
```

In order to minimise porting issues, I decided to do the integration with Matlab entirely indirectly through the system command, by putting together a script with all of the components and running it by

```
system('./temp_script')
```

where temp_script is executable and looks like this:

```
cd /home/ben/Documents/MATLAB/StructureDiscovery/+sd/Lexis
python Lexis.py -f i /home/ben/Documents/MATLAB/StructureDiscovery/+sd/Lexis/aabb.txt >> /home/ben/Documents/MATLAB/StructureDiscovery/+sd/Lexis/lexis_results.txt
```

Now I'm running this in Ubuntu 16.04, where running the script from terminal works. Running the same script from Matlab, however, gives me the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lexis.py", line 762, in <module>
    g.GLexis(quietLog, rFlag, functionFlag, costWeight)
  File "Lexis.py", line 191, in GLexis
    (maximumRepeatGainValue, selectedRepeatOccs) = self.__retreiveMaximumGainRepeat(normalRepeatType, CostFunction.EdgeCost)
  File "Lexis.py", line 242, in __retreiveMaximumGainRepeat
    repeats = self.__extractRepeats(repeatClass)
  File "Lexis.py", line 302, in __extractRepeats
    process.stdin.write(' '.join(map(str,self.__concatenatedDAG)))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

or the error

```
  File "Lexis.py", line 251, in __retreiveMaximumGainRepeat
    idx = map(int,repeatStats[2][1:-1].split(','))[0]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ersio'
```

and I haven't been able to figure out when I get which one.

the relevant snippet for repeatStats is

```
    repeats = self.__extractRepeats(repeatClass)
    for r in repeats: #Extracting maximum repeat
        repeatStats = r.split()
        idx = map(int,repeatStats[2][1:-1].split(','))[0]
```

I don't really know what's different between Matlab calling something via system and calling it directly from terminal, so I don't know what's going wrong. On OSX 10.11, exactly the same code works.

Does anyone know about the inner workings of Matlab's system command and why it might fail to allow Python to call a subprocess?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
repeats = self.__extractRepeats(repeatClass)
for r in repeats: #Extracting maximum repeat
    repeatStats = r.split()
    idx = map(int,repeatStats[2][1:-1].split(','))[0]
```

Assuming your repeatStats[2] is xersiox,10

Then repeatStats[2][1:-1] becomes ersiox,1

Then repeatStats[2][1:-1].split(',') results in a list ['ersio', '1']

As you have you have passing entire list to the entire statement

```
idx = map(int,repeatStats[2][1:-1].split(','))[0]
# it looks like this idx = map(int, ['ersio', '1'])[0]
# it picks the first item from the list, which is 'ersio', which does not have any numerical in that.
```

Instead please try below:

```
idx = map(int,repeatStats[2][1:-1].split(',')[1])[0]
# or provide an index of the item in the list, which has a number in it.
```

Comment: If the subprocess works correctly, repeatStats[2] is a list of (numerical) indices, in brackets.

Comment: Can you try by removing stdin=subprocess.PIPE?

Comment: This fails because then process.stdin is None, which means I can't use process.stdin.write

Comment: How big is your input? (stdin)

Comment: @serrapaladin PIPE has a limit, so would like to know how big is your input through stdin PIPE